# Is it wrong to instantiate an object with 'self.obj =' vs '_obj ='

Tags: objective-c

I'm not sure this ever actually matters, but as I understand it, Xcode automatically creates setters and getters with `@property`'s.

Thus I've been told its could potentially be dangerous to instantiate `self.obj = [[Obj alloc] init]` (compared to `_obj = [[Obj alloc] init]`) because `self.obj` will go through the setter when the object potentially doesn't exist yet (or something like that?).

If anyone could clarify would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main concern with using setters in initializers it that setters might have side effects, which can cause the object to be used before it's initializer had a chance to properly setup the object.

For example have a the property setter that sends a notification when the property changes. For an object receiving that notification, accessing the sender could cause problems as that object is not yet fully initialized, thus might generate undefined behaviour.

On the other hand, direct set of ivars doesn't have any side effects and is safe(r).

Assuming that you're auto-synthesizing all your properties, you might think you're safe, and yes for now you can use either the property or the ivar in init, however you never know in the future if you or someone else adds a setter for one of the properties, so better stay on the safe side.

Answer (score 2):

In the vast majority of cases, you should use `self.obj`. There are two common exceptions:

- `init`
- `dealloc`

During init, you generally don't want to call the setter because it may have side-effects that expect the rest of the object to be in a sane state (which it may not yet be).

During dealloc, you generally don't want to call the setter because it may have side-effects that expect the the object to be in a sane state (which it may no longer be).

Other than those cases, you generally want to use `self.obj` unless there is some other specific reason you need to bypass the setter.